# android retrieve one or few values from arraylist from database

Tags: android

I have made a database and arraylist  [android passing variables from inside database class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485685/android-passing-variables-from-inside-database-class)  , now I am trying to get one or some values from the array list using `List<EntryEffectiveRate> allEffectiveRate = db.getAllEffectiveRates();` as for get the all the data lists from the database, however i only able to get all of them using loop :

```
 // getting all ER
                Log.d("Get ER", "GEtting All ER");

                List<EntryEffectiveRate> allEffectiveRate = db.getAllEffectiveRates();
                for (EntryEffectiveRate ER : allEffectiveRate) {
                    Log.d("ER_ids", String.valueOf(ER.getERId()));
                    Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
                    Log.d("ER_tenors", String.valueOf(ER.getERTenor()));
                    Log.d("ER_rates", String.valueOf(ER.getERrate()));
                }
```

how to get just one or few values from the array list?

thanks in advance.

The solution is on the above link, check on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new function that takes a parameter that you can pass to the where clause of your query.

Doing this, you won't have to do any filtering on the `ArrayList` that's returned from your `DatabaseMaster` class.

You can create a different function to filter on each database entry you need.

For example, to filter on a certain `KEY_ER_USEDORNEW` value, the new function would be something like this:

```
public List<EntryEffectiveRate> getSomeERates(String USEDORNEW) {
        List<EntryEffectiveRate> EffectiveRates = new ArrayList<EntryEffectiveRate>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE + " where " + KEY_ER_USEDORNEW + " = ?";

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {USEDORNEW});

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                EntryEffectiveRate ergt = new EntryEffectiveRate();

                ergt.setERKondisi(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW)));              
                // add
                EffectiveRates.add(ergt);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        // db.close();
        c.close();
        return EffectiveRates;
    }
```

To call this from your Activity, you would pass the filter value as a parameter:

```
           String USEDORNEW = "Baru";
           List<EntryEffectiveRate> someEffectiveRates = db.getSomeERates(USEDORNEW);
            for (EntryEffectiveRate ER : someEffectiveRates) {           
                Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
            }
```

Comment: would you please also tell me how to call this function in the activity class? (an example)

Comment: @JediFighter I just realized that initially I used the wrong function as a reference.  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

i am posting a sample method that i just write in my project, definately it will be according to your requirement.

```
public ArrayList<SomeModelClass> GetCatagoriesName() {
    close();
    database = this.dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<SomeModelClass> catagory_List = new ArrayList<SomeModelClass>();
    String selectQuery = " SELECT " + KEY_CATAGORIES + " FROM "
            + TABLE_CATAGORIES;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                catagory_List.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return catagory_List;
}
```

on the other side, just get it from arraylist with position 0, no need to iterate over for loop.

Comment: This is good code, but he already had this functionality in place.  You can see it in the link to his other question.

Comment: @DanielNugent  i always give hints, never did spoon feeding bro, yes i checked, that's y i post a worked around.

Comment: I did just notice one thing in your code though, be sure to close your cursor!  Otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Many Thanks, even i saw the same error on logcat, but due to workload i ignored that. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use ...

```
List.get(index);
```

method for getting the specific or one value from the list without looping it. But if you want more then one value then you have to loop it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following code to get just one value from arraylist

```
   List<EntryEffectiveRate> allEffectiveRate =  db.getAllEffectiveRates();
   EntryEffectiveRate ER =allEffectiveRate.get(position);
   Log.d("ER_ids", String.valueOf(ER.getERId()));
   Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
   Log.d("ER_tenors", String.valueOf(ER.getERTenor()));
   Log.d("ER_rates", String.valueOf(ER.getERrate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

//use for loop as like below

```
for(int i=0;i<allEffectiveRate.size();i++)
  { 
     EntryEffectiveRate ER =allEffectiveRate.get(i);  
     Log.d("ER_ids"String.valueOf(ER.getERId()) ;
     Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
     Log.d("ER_tenors", String.valueOf(ER.getERTenor()));
      Log.d("ER_rates", String.valueOf(ER.getERrate()));
```

}

---

//if after that u can't get propar data at then problem with ur method //db.getAllEffectiveRates();